# Multiple/separate entries for single field during form submission

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a form on my ASP MVC3 website that needs to allow for multiple entries for one of it's fields prior to the form being submitted. It is for a sales agent's information, however since we outsource our sales staff one agent could have multiple companies they work with.

This form used to be provided by an Access database. The company information was input using the form below, which was built into the main form:

[image]

This would allow the user to select from DSS Company designation and input the company (or Agency Stat) Id, hit the forward arrow, and input the next until finished. The user also had the ability for cycle back and forth through their entries prior to submitting the form.

Does anyone know of any specific Ajax or JQuery plugins or techniques that I could use to implement this on an ASP MVC3 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using a [`variable length list`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which would allow you to dynamically add/remove records to a view model collection.

Your view model might look like this:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCompanyId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<selectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
    public string AgencyStat { get; set; }
}
```

and then of course your view will be strongly typed to an `IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>`. You would have add/remove links that would allow the user to add or remove records to this list and finally when he decides to submit the form your HttpPost controller action will receive the collection for further processing.